# Nested Select Count Query with Criteria

Tags: nhibernate, count, criteria

say that we have 2 entity EntityA and EntityB , with the related tables, TableA and TableB.

i have to implement this query:

```
select a.Id , (select count(b.Id) from TableB b where b.FKa = a.Id and b.AnotherField > 0) as TheCount
from TableA a
```

i'm very close to that since i wrote this code:

```
var subCrit = DetachedCriteria.For<EntityB>
                                        .Add<EntityB>(e => e.AnotherField > 0)
                                        .SetProjection(LambdaProjection.Count<EntityB>(e => e.Id).As("TheCount"));

var crit = Session.CreateCriteria<EntityA>
                        .SetProjection(LambdaProjection.GroupProperty<EntityA>(e => e.Id).As("Id),
                                            Projections.SubQuery(subCrit));
```

if i execute this criteria i obtain the following SQL:

```
select a.Id as Id , (select count(b.Id) from TableB b where b.AnotherField > 0) as TheCount from TableA a
```

as u can see , it's very close to what i'm trying to achieve...the problem (and it's definetely a big problem :D)
is that theres no link between the subquery and the entities of TableA ( where b.FKa = a.Id ).
I cant find a way to correlate the subquery to the external query via criteria.

Any suggestions ?

Ta a lot

Alessandro

**EDIT:**

changing the point of view i also could do something like that:

```
 var crit = Session.CreateCriteria<EntityA>()
                   .CreateAlias<EntityB>(a => a.B, () => b);
                   .SetProjection(LambdaProjection.Count<A>(a => b.Id).As("TheCount"),
                   .SetProjection(LambdaProjection.GroupProperty<EntityA>(a => a.Id));
```

and this is generating the following sql:

```
select count(b.Id) as TheCount, a.Id as IDa
from TableA a left outer join TableB b
on a.Id = b.FKa
group by a.Id
```

but here you can see that the additional where clause b.AnotherField > 0 is missing , and i dont know how to insert it just for the count.

Hope it's clear , thanks again

Comment: Have you considered using nHibernate bags? They are the way nHibernate handles foreign keys.

Comment: i think i should have posted the complete scenario..anyway i cannot use bags there for a domain constraint, i know it's quite a twisted scenario but that's what i have to implement.

Comment: edited the main post with another possible scenario

Answer (score 3):

Here is the solution:

```
var condition = Expression.Gt("b.AnotherField",0);
var conditionalProjection = Projections.Conditional(condition, Projections.Constant(1), Projections.Constant(0));

crit = Session.CreateCriteria<EntityA>()
                   .CreateAlias<EntityB>(a => a.B, () => b);
                   .SetProjection(Projections.Count(conditionalProjection).As("TheCount"),
                     (LambdaProjection.GroupProperty<EntityA>(a => a.Id));
```

and this is the sql generated:

select count(case b.AnotherField > 0 then 1 else 0 end) as TheCount , a.Id
from TableA a inner join TableB b

hope it can be useful

cheers

Alessandro

```
enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to change the SQL Statement

SELECT a.is, count(a.id) 
FROM TableA a 
JOIN TableB b ON a.id = b.fka AND b.af > 0
GROUP by a.ID

And create for it easy criteria.

Comment: Unfortunately i cannot change the sql statement as u suggested becuase in the same sql statement i have to return all the rows of TableA , not only the ones with the additional where clause..at the same time i have to count only the rows that satisfies that where clause. that's the why of the subquery for the count.

Comment: unfortunately not..cause if you add the restrictions to the aliased b , that restriction will be added in the where clauses .. what i want is to have a conditional count...and fortunately i found the working solution :) i'll post it in a few mins